# textView not showing in emulator for one activity but same xml makes visible in another

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 identical textViews on 2 different activities but the first textView is invisible in the emulator, despite the second being visible (on the other activity). Both are visible in the preview.

I copy and pasted the xml code from the first activity to the second and changed the id accordingly so all of the attributes are exactly the same for both

```
//Textview in first activity (not visible in emulator)

<TextView
            android:layout_width="134dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="1st Activity"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.207"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:textSize="24sp" 
android:textAlignment="center" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="141dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="279dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"/>

//textView in second activity (visible in emulator)

<TextView
            android:layout_width="134dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="2nd Activity"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.207"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textSize="24sp" 
android:textAlignment="center" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="141dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="279dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"/>
```

Everything else in both activities is exactly the same so both should be visible

[design view of the problem activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXDoM.jpg)

[emulator view of problem activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vew44.jpg)

Comment: Please note I am very new to android studio/kotlin

Comment: nothing is wrong with the text view, unless something else stands on top of it and blocks it in the first activity, or somewhere in your code you either make it invisible or gone. if you want more details i need to see more of the xml views. is the button showing correctly?(because of text depending on it) try wrap_content in height

Comment: I've edited the question to include picture links, the only code i've made is to change the activity and its the same for the other activity (which shows the textView). Yes the button shows fine

Comment: So using wrap content worked to display the textView, but is this something I'll have to do every time? Why didn't I have to do it for the other activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing height to `wrap_content` and set the `android:textColor="@android:color/black"` and see if that works